# I used Emacs to compile .sml, and I enctounter the error :"the unclosed string"

Tags: emacs, sml

I used Emacs to compile .sml, and I encounter the error:

```
stdIn:1.6-1.10 Error: unclosed string
```

As seen in this screenshot:

> [image: Screenshot of Emacs sml-mode failing]

Once I use the command `use ***(sml file)`, it failed.

No matter what I write, it always has the same error.

Comment: With the caveat that I'm unfamiliar with ML/SML... In your screenshot the `lec1.sml` buffer is modified/un-saved, so the saved file might contain that error.  The question might be less ambiguous if it was clear that the saved file matched the buffer contents.

Comment: Perhaps you need `use "D:\\PL ..."` rather than `use "D:\PL..."` to properly escape `"\"`.

Comment: Or `D:/PL ...` (forward slashes).

Comment: Without knowing the version of Emacs or sml-mode, and without getting feedback from comments, it is hard to provide an answer.

Comment: Enter `"C:\P"` and `"C:\n"` and compare the results. Then read about the escape character `'\'`.